# Contador de caracteres digitados em um textarea

Tags: javascript

Tenho essa caixa de texto para ser validada, devendo informar a quantidade de caracteres restantes e mostrar esses caracteres restantes no span, poderiam me ajudar?

```html
<div class="novaLinha">
  <div>
    <label for="txtVoce">Faleme sobre você:</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="txtVoce" name="txtVoce" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
    <p><span id="carResTxtVoce" style="font-weight: bold;">400</span> caracteres restantes</p>
    <p class="aviso" id="avisoTxtVoce" style="display:none;">Este campo não pode ficar vazio!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
var info = document.getElementById('carResTxtVoce');
var limite = 400;
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', verificar);

function verificar(e) {
    var qtdcaracteres = this.value.length;
    var restantes = limite - qtdcaracteres;
    if (restantes < 1) {
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, limite);
        return info.innerHTML = 0;
    }
    info.innerHTML = restantes;
}
```

Dessa maneira vais informando a quantidade de caracteres em falta e quando excederem o limite corta o excesso.

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/bsy6m8b7/

Também podes, como o [@Gabriel Rodrigues sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113089/contador-de-caracteres-digitados-em-um-textarea/113090?noredirect=1#comment234828_113090) podes juntar no HTML do textarea o atributo `maxlength="400"` é melhor, e nesse caso fica mais simples e pode ser só assim:

```
function verificar(e) {
    var qtdcaracteres = this.value.length;
    var restantes = limite - qtdcaracteres;
    info.innerHTML = restantes;
}
```

Comment: +1, acredito que voce deva acrescentar um `maxlength="400"`no textarea para evitar que digitem mais caracteres e corta-los, fica mais natural.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues obrigado. Em relação à tua sugestão isso já está lá. Na linha `this.value = this.value.slice(0, limite);`

Comment: o maxlength do html intercepta mais rapido do que o keyup do javascript, entáo quando ele for digitar o caractere 400 a letra nem aparecera para que depois ela seja cortada.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues pensei que estavas a sugerir via JavaScript. No HTML é bem melhor que via JavaScript. Juntei isso na resposta, obrigado.

Comment: da pra deixar mais enxuto assim:https://jsfiddle.net/bsy6m8b7/1/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues exato, se o limite for defenido no HTML fica bem assim.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup

```
<p>Typing in the input box below updates the key count</p>
<input ng-keyup="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0"> key up count: {{count}}

<p>Typing in the input box below updates the keycode</p>
<input ng-keyup="event=$event">
<p>event keyCode: {{ event.keyCode }}</p>
<p>event altKey: {{ event.altKey }}</p>
```